# Unable to find rich autocomplete id during input validation with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, jsf, autocomplete, richfaces

I have a rich:autocomplete field along with a few text input fields under a rich:panel. During input validation with the following code, all text input fields are found however the rich autocomplete field is not. The id for all input including autocomplete ends with "`_REQ`" for required. The rich:panel id is passed in as `sectionId`

```
$('div[id*="'+sectionId+'"]').find('input[id$="_REQ"]').each(function(){
    
    console.log("found:" + $(this).attr('id') + " ,value:" + $.trim($(this).val()))

    //... validation begins
    
});
```

Why am I unable to find the rich autocomplete element?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

id of autocomplete was changing after deployment, possibly due to JSF.

Comment: Did you find out if it was due to JSF

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).